# How to replace a number in my dataframe (the header also has digits)?

Tags: r

I have a  tab data-frame as follows where the 1st row and column are headers:

```
Marker  DS_123_ DS_246 DS_789    
10103   1   1   0    
10104   1   1   1    
10105   -   1   0
```

I need to replace the 1s with 2s within the dataset (without changing the headings)

I tried using the following code:

```
file1 <- data.frame(lapply(file, function(x) {
                    gsub("1", "2", x)
               }))
```

Expected output:

```
Marker  DS_123_ DS_246 DS_789    
10103   2   2   0       
10104   2   2   2    
10105   -   2   0
```

The output that I got:

```
X.c.20203..20204..20205..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can try using apply here:

```
file <- data.frame(apply(file, 2, function(x) {
    ifelse(x == "1", "2", x)
}))
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems it would be better to use `apply` here:

```
file1 <- apply(file, 2, function(x) {
  gsub("1", "2", x)
})
```

Comment: This would replace `"11"` with `"22"`.

Comment: That's a good point. And that might be the intention as well? :) If all 1s need to be replaced with 2s, or just the value of 'number 1'.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help Sven, but I needed to change all the 1s to 2s in the data frame without affecting the headers. :)